# CPanel - Error login “A fatal error or timeout occurred while processing this directive. ”

Tags: server, cpanel

I face this problem multiple time. It happen when I put my login information on cpanel login, then the page goes empty except these message:

```
Template::Exception:
    [TYPE]=[file]
    [INFO]=[parse error - home/retro/stats_bar.html.tt line 84-90: unexpected token (%)
  [% IF stat.pc.defined;
                stat.percent = stat.pc;
        [%
            IF stat.pc.defined;
                stat.percent = stat.pc;
            END; %]]
    [TEXT]=[ 






]
 at cpanel.pl line 1050.
    cpanel::cpanel::cptt_exectag("/usr/local/cpanel/base/frontend/paper_lantern/index.auto.tmpl", 1) called at cpanel.pl line 4408
    cpanel::cpanel::run_standard_mode() called at cpanel.pl line 864
    cpanel::cpanel::script("cpanel::cpanel", "./frontend/paper_lantern/index.html") called at cpanel.pl line 271
```

I tried to re-install the cpanel by using this command `scripts/upcp --force` it goes good. But the next day happen again, at the exact time of 11:30 am.

I opened CPanel support ticket, but it has been a day, and no reply yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Hello,

*If you running just cpanel*, do *cpanel* force update
**"/scripts/upcp --force"**
If you running cpanel with *CloudLinux* do LVE Manager updated
**"yum update lvemanager"**

Visit https://www.cloudlinux.com/cloudlinux-os-blog/entry/lve-manager-updated-1-6

## lvemanager-2.0-41 1

1. WEB-689: set Content-type: text/html in CloudLinux.cgi;
2. WEB-839: fixed broken cPanel's styles when "LVE Manager" plugin is opened (cPanel 11.69.9999 only);
3. LVEMAN-1203: fixed retro theme errors on cPanel EDGE (11.70);
4. LVEMAN-1188: improved StatsBar integration in cPanel WHM.

Comment: Thanks, it works good. Simply using script upcp doesnt work so good untill the cloudlinux has to be update to.

Comment: @ahmed zeaad thanks for the answer, just the updated `/scripts/upcp --force` saved my day. Thanks again